# For SharePoint Online, is it possible to install an app globally for a Hub Site Collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, visual-web-part, app, app-store

I am looking for the ability to install an app for my collection of sites and manage the app's content from a central location, but add the corresponding web part to pages in several different sites under the same Hub.

Currently, I have the app installed and working, but the content I am adding to the app is only available within that specific site. I added the app to the Hub site in the collection hoping the content would then be available throughout the internal sites, but that isn't the case.

When I go to another site within the collection, the web part for the app isn't available on the page. But, I can go to "add an app" to that site and it is available within my library. I do not need to install it from the app store again.

Specifically, if this helps, looking into this app: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104379252?tab=Overview

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the app to each site. You can either do this via adding a local app catalog to each site, then adding the app, or deploying the app to the central app catalog and installing the app to your sites. Hub sites do not support app-push down.

Comment: thanks for the details! So I have to have an individual app install for each site if I want the corresponding web-part available for that given site?

Comment: Either install the package globally in the central app catalog or if you want to limit the install of the app to specific sites, deploy it to the site collection app catalog and install it to that same site.